# How can I conditionally validate a custom rule in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, web-frameworks, laravel-validation, laravel-7

In my controller I have a `store` method that is validating the request data:

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'date' => [
        'required',
        new DateFormatRule
    ],
    'closed' => 'nullable',
    'time_start' => 'required_if:closed,0',
    'time_end' => [
        'required_if:closed,0',
        new TimeDurationRule($request->time_start)
    ],
]);
```

`closed` is a boolean. If `closed` is false, the `time_start` and `time_end` fields are required. This seems to be working as expected.

However, if I submit a request with `closed` as true, I am getting caught in my custom `TimeDurationRule`:

```
'time_end' => [
    'required_if:closed,0',
    new TimeDurationRule($request->time_start)
],
```

How can I make `new TimeDurationRule($request->time_start)` conditional? For example, if `closed` is true, I am manually setting `time_end` to `null` so `time_start`/`time_end` do not need a value (not required).

If I comment my custom rule out, everything works as expected.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `$request->closed` to your `TimeDurationRule` and then in the `passes` method of the `rule`, you can do something like this:

```php
class TimeDurationRule implements Rule
{
    public $closed;

    public function __construct(/*all needed parameters*/, $closed)
    {
        $this->closed = $closed;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if(!$closed){ 
         return true
        }

        // the rest of validation logic
    }
}
```

And then

```php
new TimeDurationRule(/*all needed parameters*/, $request->closed)
```

You can read more about it here as well: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/create-custom-validation-rule-with-additional-parameters-implement-in-request

Hope it helps!

Comment: I feel really silly. I didn't realize I could pass additional params to the rule like that. Thought it was just a 1:1 rule that only evaluated the one argument. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Damon no problem! Rule is just a class like all the others, so you can do whatever you want with the constructor and similar.